# Its -38 and car wont start

Tags: engine, radiator, fuel-line

So I ran out of gas in -40°c we filled the tank and put in fuel line antifreeze,  tried starting the car and it cranks but wont turn over so we had no choice but to leave it for 2 days due to the cold. We have it plugged in at home but it still wont start my question is how long does it take for a car to thaw out and how can I get it started?

Comment: How can you says « it cranks but won’t turn over » ? Either the engine cranks or it does not.

Comment: When you say plugged in do you mean an engine block heater, as in it is outside? An engine block heater won't thaw your fuel line.

Answer (score 1):

If the block heater functions you will be able to feel the heat by touching the engine after 4-5 hrs,it is not a problem to have the block heater on overnight.

If you are unable to feel the heat after multiple hrs the block heater does not funcktion so it needs to be replaced or it might be a bad connection before the heating element.

Here comes a pro tip on how to get the car started in cold climate.

When it is that cold i suggest you take the battery inside your house overnight to heat it up,if you get the temparature above freezing in your battery this will help a lot.

a cold battery will not be able to give the power needed for you to start the engine in the low temparature you have there.